# Is there a simple way to convert Option[Task[T]] to Task[Option[T]]?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, reactive-programming, zio, monix

While using [monix.eval.Task](https://monix.io/docs/current/eval/task.html) or [zio.Task](https://zio.dev/docs/datatypes/core/task), is there a simple way to convert [Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) of Task to Task of Option?

Comment: Vice versa is not possible since it would need to evaluate the Task which breaks the whole idea.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I don't need vice versa and updated the question.

Comment: You should look up `Traversable`. This trait is exactly what is needed here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a pure ZIO solution, you can use `.foreach` with `identity`:

```
val fx: Option[UIO[Int]] = Option(Task.effectTotal(42))
val res: UIO[Option[Int]] = ZIO.foreach(fx)(identity)
```

If you're also using `cats`, the method you're looking for is called `.sequence`.

```
import cats.implicits.toTraverseOps
import zio.interop.catz._
import zio.{Task, UIO}

val fx: Option[UIO[Int]] = Option(Task.effectTotal(42))
val res: UIO[Option[Int]] = fx.sequence
```

The other way around is not possible as one would need to materialize the `Task` in order to be able to lift it into an `Option[T]`.